# How return -1; works and what it is used for?

Tags: java

How `return -1;` works and what it is used for?

For example in code below:

```
   public static double calFeetAndInchesToCentimeters (double inches) {
    if (inches <0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid statement-2");
        return -1;
    } else {
        return (inches/12);
    }

}
```

Please explain.
Thank you!

Comment: If you are gonna use this function somewhere. You will know if the function executed correctly based on return value.

Comment: It's no different than `return (inches/12)` as far as the mechanism is concerned. But the code calling this method `calFeetAndInchesToCentimeters` can check the returned value, and if it's -1, it can tell that something went wrong. Note that there are better ways to detect and throw errors, but this should be sufficient to start exploring further.

Comment: Note that a centimeter is not 1/12 of an inch - the method does not do what its name suggests (convert from inches to centimeters).

Comment: You can print errors with `System.err.println`. If this is production code, then you should try to avoid `System.out.println` unless it is a console application where the user must necessarily see that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not do that in Java.

Usually, returning -1 is an idiomatic way to tell that an error occurred. This is often use in languages like C where there are no exception mechanisms. Also, other negative values can be used in order to indicate the source of the problem when several different errors can occur.

The calling method would do something like this :

```java
double feet = calFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(length);
if(feet >= 0) {
  // valid value, continue the execution
} else {
  // log an error and stop the execution
}
```

This is a bad practice in Java because if you forget to handle the error, the program will continue with an invalid value, resulting in a silent bug.

The right way to do it in Java would be :

```java
public static double calFeetAndInchesToCentimeters (double inches) {
if (inches <0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("inches must be non-negative");
} else {
  return (inches/12);
}
```

and the calling method would handle it like that :

```
try {
  double feet = calFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(length);
  // valid value, continue the execution
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // log an error and stop the execution
}
```

Here, if you forget to handle the error, the program will just crash and the bug will be noticed.

Comment: "and the calling method would handle it like that :" no, you shouldn't do this. You should check `length` (or otherwise ensure the method is not called for negative values) before calling the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Isn't it an opinionated design choice ? It seems to me that it would somehow duplicate the error handling : an if/else before calling the method + maybe still a thrown exception if the error handling was not exhaustive. Plus, it means that you have to duplicate this check everywhere the method is called. Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: How the calling method handles thrown exceptions is certainly context-based. So I would be afraid to include it in the answer as to not confuse new engineers.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle in the sense that both approaches can result in correctly-functioning code: yes, it is opinionated. However, there are a number of reasons why it is a bad idea to catch exceptions instead of simple checks. For one, it's really slow (constructing stack traces is far more expensive than a numeric comparison). For another, there is nothing to say that the IAE is caused by the fact that the value is negative: there could be some other reason the exception is thrown, and you are masking it by catching what you think is the "negative" IAE.

Answer (score 0):

You can not measure inches less than 0, because length can not be negative number, so your function checks if input parameter is negative and returns -1 as a result. And you can check if the input parameter is correct or wrong. I think that your question is not correct. Please see stackoverflow guide to post correct questions.